# How to give number of seekbar on android

Tags: java, android

How to give number of seekbar on android.
please answer to my question becouse I need it.
 Thank you
Xml:

```
 <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Java:

```
public class Setting extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);
}
}
```

Comment: Didn't get your question...What you want exactly?

Comment: @m.asadi, check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "DiscreteSeekBar" from below url:

https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, set a max value for the SeekBar in XML.
Add the following attribute to the SekkBar:

```
android:max="40"
```

Then in code:

```
SeekBar seekBar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
int currentValue = seekBar1.getProgress();
```

getProgress() will return the current value (from 0 to 40);

But you should use a listener for changes and get new value:

```
seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
    {
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {
            currentValue = progress;
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
        {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for 100 number as maximum seek:

```
      <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:max="100"/>
```

**Selection of seek bar**, 
    onProgressChanged provide real time selection change as you seek, but when you stop then onProgressStop is encountered, then do as you want :

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progress = 0;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                progress = progresValue;

                textView.setText(progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // Do something here, if you want to do anything at the start of
                // touching the seekbar


            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // Display the value in textview
                textView.setText(progress + "/" + seekBar.getMax());

            }
        });
```

Comment: how give number of select ?